# What are Recycler view and Card View?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I'm building a todo app in which I want my user the ability to scroll down to see more todos so I'm confused about RecyclerView and CardView 
few are saying to use just RecyclerView and few are saying to use CardView
but others are saying to use both so can you please tell me what to use and how to implement to scroll effect

`*sorry I don't understand what code should I provide*`

```
*new to stackoverflow*
```

Comment: Did you google it ?

Comment: [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview is just like to manipulate all items.
if you use card view every item has own card view and all items will be load in side recyclerview. its up to you weather you want use card view or not but recyclerview is necessary to load all items. Card view just give them different look. I hope you will understand it.

Comment: `Recyclerview is just like to manipulate all items` ?? This is as Confusing as it can be .. `Recyclerview` is just a widget to show list of items in some arrangement it can be List, Grid , Staggered etc.

Comment: yes. Recyclerview is like listview but more powerful and flexible then listview.

Answer (score 0):

you can use both for better user experience.RecyclerView is a ViewGroup added to the android studio as a successor of the GridView and ListView

CardView is mostly used for good looking UI with RecyclerView
you can design style in cardview which later used in recyclerview

hope you can understand

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is like an enhanced ListView that must have ViewHolder inside it. The ViewHolder UI of each row. So, to inflate each row UI, you also need LayoutManager.

The CardView UI component shows information inside cards. We can customise its corners, the elevation and so on. We want to use this component to show contact information. These cards can be the rows of RecyclerView.